# Can I configure Outlook 2007 and 2010 to use different "From" and "Reply-to" addresses?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have Outlook 2007 with a single IMAP mail account.  I have a number of aliases configured for that account with my provider.  Can I default Outlook to use one of those aliases for the "From" and "Reply-to" addresses when sending?

Comment: Usually, you have a choice of FROM when you add those accounts to Outlook. You could add those aliases and unsubscribe to all folders. Then try replying to an e-mail that was sent to one of your aliases. If your FROM previously was your catchall e-mail, it may change to the correct FROM now.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your ISP, you may be able to do the following:

1. Set your outgoing SMTP server to that of your ISP:  [Common SMTP Server Addresses](http://www.host45.com/resources/ispsmtps.php)
2. For your IMAP e-mail account, go into the advanced settings and find the Outgoing Server Authentication tab.  Put a mark in the radio button that says, "My Outgoing Server requires authentication" and fill in your alias e-mail address and a bogus password.

Depending on how your ISPs SMTP server is setup, it *may* use this e-mail address as the from or reply-to address when sending mail.

Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

In the ribbon, select `Options`, then try select 'Direct Reply' or something like that. Then a dialog box will open and there will be an option to add a new email address.

When the recipient will reply, it will reply to  new address provided.